# Can't see udp packets with nc command, works with tcpdump

Tags: ip, udp, tcpdump, netcat, alpine

I'm trying to capture UDP data using the `nc` (`netcat`) command but it doesn't output anything. What options/parameters do I need to pass to the `nc` command to get the output?

`tcpdump` does show the UDP data. The reason I'm trying `nc` is that when I know how to capture I can use these settings in another program that eventualy needs to listen for the incomming data.

Things I've tried with `nc` are:

```
$ nc -ul 8002
$ nc -ulb 8002
$ nc -u -l -s 192.168.2.235 -p 8002
$ nc -u -l -s 192.168.2.255 -p 8002
$ nc -u -l -b -s 192.168.2.235 -p 8002
$ nc -u -l -b -s 192.168.2.255 -p 8002
$ nc -u -l -b -s 255.255.255.255 -p 8002
$ nc -u -l -s 192.168.2.235 8002
$ nc -u -l -s 192.168.2.255 8002
$ nc -u -l -s 255.255.255.255 8002
```

All resulted in no ouput.

The working `tcpdump` command:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -A -i eth1 'udp port 8002'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
12:42:32.823653 IP 192.168.1.52.5678 > 255.255.255.255.8002: UDP, length 23
E..3....@......4.......B....$RADPT,5.5,0.0,40,*57

12:42:32.987098 IP 192.168.1.53.5678 > 255.255.255.255.8002: UDP, length 24
E..4~(..@.:....5.......B. ..$RBDPT,0.04,0.0,40,*60
```

My network configuration:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:02:89:17:be:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4e02:89ff:fe17:bede/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:02:89:17:be:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.235/24 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4e02:89ff:fe17:bedf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:02:89:17:be:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:02:89:17:be:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:02:89:17:be:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:22:77:fb:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:22ff:fe77:fb27/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: slcan0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can
12: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.24.1.3/16 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The data is received on eth1, I can't change the ip/netmask of eth0 because then I'll lose the connection to the computer (everthing is running remote). The OS is Linux Alpine.

Comment: Note that tcpdump can capture packets before they will be discarded by a local firewall (iptables) and thus can display packets that won't reach the listener which you create with `nc` ; so check that your local firewall configuration allows traffic to port 8002

Comment: In addition to the firewall, having rp_filter=1 (following SRPF : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3704#section-2.2) would be enough to get the packet dropped: wrong interface.